# How to cast to dyn Trait when creating a Box<dyn Trait>

Tags: rust

In the following code:

```rust
trait Animal {}
struct Dog {}
impl Animal for Dog {}
fn main() {
    // first two lines are OK as expected
    let _animal1: Box<dyn Animal> = Box::new(Dog {});
    let _animal2: Box<dyn Animal> = Box::new(Dog {}) as Box<dyn Animal>;
    // next line is a compile error: cast to unsized type: `Dog` as `dyn Animal`
    let _animal3: Box<dyn Animal> = Box::new(Dog {} as dyn Animal);
}
```

Why is it an error to cast `Dog{}` to `dyn Animal`?

For this example, compiler correctly infer the type and the cast is redundant. However for the general case, what should be used to provide type information to compiler instead of `dyn Animal`.

To state the question in a different way: what is the type of object given to `Box::new()`, if it is not `dyn Animal`?

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that every reference to an object (e.g. `&T`, `&mut T`, `Box<T>`, `Arc<T>` etc) can exist *without* knowing the size of an object (e.g. fulfilling the `Sized` trait). Which is the case in your first two lines in the example.

However, in the third line, you briefly (before passing it into `Box::new()`) cast it into `dyn Animal`, which is **not** a reference, but instead an object.
Every object that exists in Rust needs to have a known size, because otherwise Rust wouldn't know how much space to allocate for it on the stack. This isn't an issue for references, because references have a constant size independent of the object they are referencing.

Consider this:

```rust
let dog = Dog{};
// Works
let _animal : &dyn Animal = &dog as &dyn Animal;
// Fails
let _animal : dyn Animal = dog as dyn Animal;
```

I think the error message is very explanatory:

```
error[E0620]: cast to unsized type: `Dog` as `dyn Animal`
  --> src/main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |     let _animal : dyn Animal = dog as dyn Animal;
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: consider using a box or reference as appropriate
  --> src/main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |     let _animal : dyn Animal = dog as dyn Animal;
   |                                ^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0620`.
```

---

The second part of your question is 'what should I use to cast dog into an animal?'.

I'd answer with: It depends on whether or not you want to carry over ownership.

If you do *not* want to carry over ownership and instead keep the original object:

```rust
let dog = Dog{};
let animal: &dyn Animal = &dog;
```

Else, if you want to move ownership into the animal object:

```
let dog = Dog{};
let animal: Box<dyn Animal> = Box::new(dog);
```

Comment: Ok, I got your point. But then, what should I use for cast? `&dyn Animal` will also not work.

Comment: What's the problem with the first two ways you did it?

Comment: Updated the answer to address that part of your question more explicitely

Comment: If your use case is more specific than that, you would have to provide a more specific example.

Comment: I just want to understand what is the type of thing that is given to `Box::new()`.

Comment: It's `Dog`. The cast to `dyn Animal` happens after it is wrapped in a `Box`.

Comment: As mentioned in @rodrigo's answer, (if I understand it correctly), the conversion happens here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html#impl-CoerceUnsized%3CBox%3CU%2C%20A%3E%3E
Which defines that a Box<A> can be coerced into a Box<B> if A implements B

Comment: @Finomnis: Actually it is a bit more [complicated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-CoerceUnsized%3CBox%3CU%2C%20A%3E%3E) than that, but that is the net result.

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler says, you cannot cast to a `dyn` type, because it is unsized. That is, a value of type `dyn T` cannot exist in the stack.

You can only use `dyn` types behind a pointer-like construct, such as `&dyn _` or `Box<dyn _>`, because the additional level of indirection means that the `dyn` object itself does not exist, it is only a construction of the type system.

Those handle the inner conversion automatically. As you noticed you don't event need an explicit cast, the coercion is implicit.

These pointer like types do the conversion via the magic [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) trait (still unstable).

Comment: So, it is not possible to state a type for the case when automatic coercion does not work.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu That's nothing new to Rust, btw. It *is* possible in C++ to cast classes to abstract superclasses, but that introduces object slicing. My guess is that is the reason why it's forbidden in Rust. Correct me if I'm wrong, rodrigo.

Comment: `CoerceUnsized` is not stable as you stated, and it is not in the stable version. So in the stable Rust, is there some other mechanism in charge?

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu: If automatic coercion does not work, you _can_ use a cast, I just stated that is it not usually needed. "Abstract classes" and and "Zero Sized Types" are actually unrelated concepts, in Rust there is no inheritance so slicing is not a thing. And `CoerceUnsized` being unstable means that you cannot use it directly in your stable programs, but it will still do its work, indirectly.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu: Ah, I see your reasoning about super-classes in C++. In C++ a superclass can be smaller in size, even zero sized (assuming EBO), and a cast to a superclass will do the dreaded slice. And in Rust a `dyn Trait` works a bit like a superclass so a direct cast should not be allowed. So now I think it is a good analogy for a C++ programer about why this is not allowed. Except that slicing is not even a thing in Rust (no subclasses) and there are other types of dynamically sized types (DST) in the language with similar limitations.

Comment: BTW, where I said "Zero Sized Type" (ZST) I meant "Dynamically Sized Type" (DST), a totally different thing.

Comment: The C++ comment was actually me, not him. I was trying to make it more graspable by comparing similar concepts of a potentially more familiar language.